# how to navigate among open VS Code open windows on Mac

Tags: visual-studio-code

I recently updated Visual Studio Code to a new version (1.7.2) on my Mac.
I am used to open different 'windows' of VS Code at the same time on different projects.
In previous versions of VS Code I could navigate the VS Code open windows via 'cmd+>' (or 'cmd+z', now I do not remember this exaclty).
Now this key combination does not work anymore and, to navigate windows, I need to open the 'Window' menu option and chose from there.
Does anybody know how to navigate among open VS Code open windows on Mac with this version of VS Code?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`cmd+<` is not provided by VSCode, it's a global shortcut of OSX witch works for all applications with multiple windows. You can check if its properly set up in Preferences->Keyboard->Shortcuts
[image]

However, there is a command in VSCode to select open windows from a list. Search the command palette for `Switch Window`, you can bind it to a shortcut yourself, command is called `workbench.action.switchWindow`.

Comment: My MBP defaults "Move focus to next window" to CMD+`. When I try this key combination nothing happens, in VSC I have to go to Window menu and manually select which window to switch to. Is this answer no longer correct, or is there something wrong with how my MBP is configured.

Comment: I think `workbench.action.switchWindow` comes from some extension you had back then. To do it in 2022, click the `...` button at the top right corner and select **Show Opened Editors**

Answer (score 5):

**control+w** is working for me

It is showing all active windows